# How to type a character sequence with in the https://hackertyper.net/ webpage using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I made a post earlier about making the bot, and it works, thanks to Justin Ezequiel, but it stops randomly. Any fixes?

Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

x = 1

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://hackertyper.net/')
while x == 1:
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.send_keys("I'm trying to make a bot to see how far I can get in hackertyper")
    actions.perform()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within [Hacker Typer](https://hackertyper.net/) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://hackertyper.net/')
  x = 1
  while x == 1:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='main']//pre//span[@id='cursor']")))).send_keys("I'm trying to make a bot to see how far I can get in hackertyper").perform()
      time.sleep(0.5)
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://hackertyper.net/')
  x = 1
  while x == 1:
      ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#main pre span#cursor")))).send_keys("I'm trying to make a bot to see how far I can get in hackertyper").perform()
      time.sleep(0.5)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: hackertyper.png]